# Relative formal punctured disc and its étale covers

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I asked a similar question before with no answer but I'll try again. Let $A$ be an algebra over $\mathbb{C}$.  You can assume it's reduced and of finite type (if you can relax the latter assumption that would be great).

I'd like to know the $z$-adically complete étale covers of $spec(A((z)))$. I'd like them all to be of the form $spec(B((z^{\frac{1}{n}})))$ for étale $A$-algebra $B$.  The analogous question for Laurent polynomials as opposed to power series seems to follow from the Riemann existence theorem.